# Erlang dots and boxes, stuck

Tags: erlang

I am trying to make a simple dots and boxes game in erlang where two processes play the game. I am trying to store the state of the walls in an array of booleans like this,

```
Rooms = array:new([{default, false}, {size, ?SIZE}]).
```

but I'm not sure how to graphically display the state of the board. I want to draw the grid, and a space if the booleans are false, and a _ or | if they are true. The thing is, I have no idea how to do this. The documentation on io:fwrite or io:format is less than helpful, and I don't really understand any of it. I'm also not sure if I'm even going about this the right way. Is it even practical to do this with an array of booleans? I wanted to use arrays since they are mutable, everything else isn't. Can someone please provide some help or advice on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Try with something easier first, then how to do this with immutable state will make more sense. Hint: each "turn" of the game is an entry to a function that does.... what? Think of each iteration as its own totally independent slice of time, and the state thing will make more sense. Until then, trying to write this and worrying about display issues is premature.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with zxq9, I think that printing the state should come at the end. Before this you will have to setup the processes in charge to "play", the server which maintain the game, decide how to schedule the game... The nice thing is that you should be able to test each element individually. Doing this you will see which data structure is best adapted to your program.

Note that arrays aren't mutable. the following sequence shows it:

```
1> A = array:new().
{array,0,10,undefined,10}
2> B = array:set(0,a,A). % create a new array adding an element to A
{array,1,10,undefined,
       {a,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
          undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined}}
3> B = array:set(0,b,B). % attempting to change the element 0 of B will fail
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 
                    {array,1,10,undefined,
                           {b,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                              undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                              undefined}}
4> C = array:set(0,b,B). % but it is possible to modify the element and store the resulting array in a new variable
{array,1,10,undefined,
       {b,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
          undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined}}
5>
```